# mailgun module (not adapter) in Parse Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, mailgun, parse-server

In Parse server there is a node mailgun module. This is my code:

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
var mg = mailgun.client({username: 'myApi', key: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY || 'myKey'});

mg.messages.create('myUrl', {
from: "myEmail@example.com",
to: "email@example.com",
subject: "Test",
text: "Test"
  })
  .then(msg => console.log(msg)) // logs response data
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); // logs any error
```

but the console shows me this:

```
error: Uncaught internal server error. [TypeError: mailgun.client is not a function] TypeError: mailgun.client is not a function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the mailgun-js module needs to be initialized and used differently:

```
var api_key = 'key-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var domain = 'mydomain.mailgun.org';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js